# useradd command's argument issue

Tags: linux

I am getting an issue regarding the `useradd` command's argument.

I want to add a user with the `-p` option, and my process is getting an encrypted password with another process. I use the system command to invoke the `useradd` command with proper arguments but the password is not passed correct.

Then I tried to run the `useradd` command manually and got the following error:

```
useradd -d /home -m -o -p "**\$1\$LmiSHTiI\$SVop.LoJGIkYQ6MdRSNW61**" -u 0 -g 0 cpu
```

I used the encrypted value of "cpu123".

`strace` snapshot:

```
execve("/usr/sbin/useradd", ["useradd", "-d", "/home", "-m", "-o", "-p",     
  "**$1$LmiSHTiI$SVop.LoJGIkYQ6MdRSNW**", "-u", "0", "-g", "0", "cpu"], 
  [/* 36 vars */])
```

In the strace snapshot, I found that the last digits are not added using the `-p` option.

Comment: This argument truncation looks very strange to me. Does it also happen if you create a shell script (`#!/bin/sh`) and run it? Can you please add the full source of your shell script and the full strace output? What happens if you run the shell script with `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @pts: I am using command on my bash script. I found one thing that after 32 bit, password string is truncated.. it is also with the username. Can we change this size?

Comment: When using `strace`, did you call it using the `-s <number>` option? Otherwise, strings will be truncated to 32 characters. What is strange, though: There should be an ellipsis (`...`) after a truncated string, which doesn't appear in your snapshot.

Comment: Please provide the full shell script anyway (it can be as short as the command above), so it's easier for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Running this command manually is going to behave strangely, as variable expansion gets into your way. In bash, you should rather write `**$1$LmiSHTiI$SVop.LoJGIkYQ6MdRSNW**` in single quotes: `'**$1$LmiSHTiI$SVop.LoJGIkYQ6MdRSNW**'`. Your issue seems to lie somewhere else, though...